Movie in which a female university professor goes undercover in a comedy club
In this feature film, a stuck-up university professor goes undercover in a comedy club to find out what is changing the minds of the students. While there her fruit juice gets spiked and she can no longer resist laughing at the comedy routine, despite trying to stay composed and undercover.

I'm baffled why someone would try to close this perfectly good question for needing more detail.

I mean, not least because it's been answered.

Could this be For Those Who Think Young (1964)?
Investigating a beach club where they allegedly sell alcohol to teens, the stuffy (female) university professor has her drink spiked. For some reason she can't tell that her "fruit juice" largely consists of beer, schnapps and vodka.

